gunicorn: command not found when hosting on Railway
I am new to Django and hosting web applications, and I am trying to host my first one using Railway. The application successfully builds and deploys for about 5 seconds before crashing and giving me the error /bin/bash: line 1: gunicorn: command not found. It then tries to repeatedly restart the container, failing every time.
I have a Procfile with the line web: gunicorn EPLInsights:app, created the requirements.txt file using pip freeze > requirements.txt, and specified the runtime. I also have whitenoise installed, DEBUG set to false, and ALLOWED_HOSTS set to ['*'].
Unfortunately, there is not much more information that Railway presents with the error, so I am having trouble figuring out what is causing it. If anyone has any insight it would be greatly appreciated.
